# Изменить HTML код WordPress шаблона который часто обновляется

Tags: wordpress

Есть WordPress тема которая часто обновляется, поэтому править function.php и лезть в код - не вариант, т.к. при следующем обновлении все слетит. А нужно всего лишь поменять

```
<i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
```

На

```
<i class="fa fa-bars"></i> Меню
```

Может есть какой-то плагин? Чтобы я указал в нем, что нужно поменять X-код на Y-код.

Comment: Если тема часто обновляется и чтобы не слетало, для правок обычно используется [Child тема](https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%94%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B)

Comment: @Simon Создал дочернюю тему. А как теперь прописать эту замену?

Comment: Нужно понимать в каком файле в вашей родительской теме эта иконка находится, вам нужно будет скопировать этот файл из вашей родительской темы, в вашу дочернюю, соблюдая порядок директорий в которых этот файл находится. Я так подозреваю, это относится к меню в хедере, судя по иконке и тому что это "Меню", потому смотреть вам нужно изначально в header.php, возможно что это вынесено в template-part. Можете также сделать глобальный поиск по файлам темы, при помощи любого из редакторов кода, чтобы посмотреть в каких файлах находится нужная вам иконка.

Answer (score -1):

Нашел плагин который делает именно то, что нужно - [Real-Time Find and Replace](https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/real-time-find-and-replace/). Находит код в HTML и заменяет его на нужный.

[image: Настройка автозамены]

Comment: Вам дали верный ответ о том, что нужно использовать Child-тему

Comment: Это ещё страшнее, чем изменять DOM яваскриптом. И да правильное решение - дочерняя тема. Всегда. Кроме случаев когд тема самописная под конкретный сайт.